# how to send html sign from javascript to java as it is

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, character-encoding

In my application I am handling some of the special symbol as ™ AND ® . I tried two things.

1) If I have a value value™ , I am encoding this and its getting value%E2%84%A2 , but again % symbol getting changed to %25 .

2) so I tried to decode the value I am sending value™ from javascript to java , again it is getting changed to some unexpected character .

how can I handle this ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you get these symbol? Do you get these from an html form? Will you send as a json to java ?

Comment: From your problem description, it sounds like your encoding is being run twice, maybe once on input and then once on send? your % should not be escaped a second time

Comment: I got these symbol as part of our data , and that contains those symbol and it has to be available at the UI also.